# RExcel Addin - statconnDCOM

Tags: r, excel, excel-addins

I had the RExcel Addin but cannot get it to work 'No R process connected'.  From what I understand this is a problem with the student license of statconnDCOM.
I wonder if anyone has been able to find a solution for this. I have contacted the creators of the RExcel Addin but statconnDCOM is maintained/sold by a third party but does not offer a student license.
Did I miss something?
Anyone any idea how to make this RExcel Addin work again or an alternative solution?

Comment: Are you sure you need it? You can [run R scripts inside Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-r-in-query-editor), including the (free) Power BI Desktop edition.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have used this in the past and it works very well where you call R function from within Excel see for instance the article by Baier Creating and Deploying an Application with (R)Excel and R.  The reason for using Excel versus PowerBI is that students are more familiar with Excel.

Comment: You should probably consider what *employers* and actual data science work requires instead. The very fact that you need to use R *and* Excel means that you can't use only a single "master" tool. You can't call *Python* from inside Excel either and yet it's an indispensable tool. In fact, SQL Server 2017 added Python support. 2016 had already added R support. Power Query in Power BI supports R scripts. Power Query in Excel doesn't yet (infuriating), so you'd have to split processing.

Comment: You can't use expensive proprietary "adapters" to open-source tools either as they aren't all that viable - why use the *adapter* instead of learning the tool well enough to split the job between R, Excel and PowerBI? Never mind that Excel will add the same R support that's available to Power BI sooner or later.

Comment: Anyway, right now it *looks* like statconn's page claims there's a Home & Student license. It also claims RExcel only works up to Excel 2013, which probably means they aren't updating their page, not thath there's any real problem with using R

Comment: There are quite a few open-source Excel to R bridges. [R.NET](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet) is a very popular library. You could use it to create your own Excel addins that don't need to go through COM. [RProvider](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/FSharpRProvider) is a type provider written in F#. What's more Tomas Petricek is a very well known member of the F# community and *answers* immediatelly. [NeXL.RNet](https://github.com/Statfactory/NeXL.RNet) is an Excel addin that uses RProvider to talk to R

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and leads.